# React Native how change size & color of secureTextEntry inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, react-native, react-native-textinput

So I have a password input like below :

```
<TextInput
   name="Password"
   type="password"
   mode="outline"
   secureTextEntry={true}
   style={styles.inputStyle}
   autoCapitalize="none"
   autoFocus={true}       
/>
```

and have this style applied to it :

```
inputStyle { 
   fontSize: 30,
   color: '#333',
   fontWeight: '900'
}
```

But it seems that these styles not actually applied to the input. however once I remove the `secureTextEntry={true}` props, it will effected. So I guess styling the password ballets is kind of difference, any idea how I can achieve it?

Comment: try 
```
inputStyle { 
   fontSize: 30,
   color: '#333',
   fontWeight: '900',
}
```
you forgot a comma between color and fontWeight, i'm sure it is not the issue, 
this issue existed in previous version of react-native, but it does not exist anymore. can you upgrade the react-native version ?

Comment: That comma was my mistyped here, I have version 0.58.3 installed which is the latest version I guess and still same issue.

Comment: somehow the issue still exist even in latest versions of `react-native` https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22781

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for color I used `textColor` prop which works fine and for some reasons when we pass the fontSize by style in not really overwrite to the default one, so what I did to fix this I define a fontSize prop :

```
export interface TextInputContainerProps {
    ... // Some other props
    fontSize?: number;
}
```

and then pass it to `TextInput` component :

```
<TextInput {...props} style={[...props.style, { fontSize }]}
    editable={editable} />
```